# Unable to persist to database in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations

After setting up my associations, I tried testing them out in the console but I am unable to persist to the DB. Im clueless as to why this is happening!

I've successfully ran all migrations and reloaded the console. Still unable to persist.

```
#Item.rb

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
end

#List.rb

class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end

#Schema

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

#Console output:
>> Item.create(:description => "Cookies")
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> <Item id: nil, description: "Cookies", list_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> cookies = Item.create(description: "Cookies")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Item id: nil, description: "Cookies", list_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> i = Item.new
=> #<Item id: nil, description: nil, list_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> i.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Item` class, you've done:

```
belongs_to :list
```

Which means that `list` is required. You're not providing a list, so the save fails. You can see this if you do:

```
Item.create!(:description => "Cookies")
```

(with a bang, which will cause an error to be thrown) in console.

If you want `list` to be optional, you need to do:

belongs_to :list, optional: true

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please feel free to upvote and accept (to help future searchers).